# How to store and retrieve array fields and value pairs in a text field in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks something like this

`array( 'cars' => 10, 'trucks' => 20, 'computers' => 50 );`

Now I want to store the field and value pairs in a database field. I also want to be able to retrieve it so the array will be in the same form as it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what **[`serialize()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)** is for

#### Slightly More Elaborated

The [`serialize()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function gets (almost) any type of value as an arguments, and outputs a storable string.

When you want to retrieve the value from the database, you use [**`unserialize()`**](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Oh that's right. I thought this only took the values, but is does take them in pairs. Really stupid of me, sorry. Will accept answer.